# Android Studio 2.3 Windows: AVDManager and SDkManager UI are gone?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I've just downloaded the latest version of Android Studio (23.2) and apparently **the AVD Manager and SDK Manager applications aren't available anymore**:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

They used to be in `\Android\sdk` . But now in the `\Android\sdk\tools\bin` folder there are multiple .bat files:

[image: Bat Files]

However neither by running the files as administrator or with the command line starts the graphical interface, they're just command line tools.

Were these apps removed in the last version? [Do i need to handle the SDK and Virtual Devices through the command line now](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it seems that the old apps aren't available anymore. Instead you should use the manager inside Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio Android SDK]

And the same should be done with [the AVD Manager (Tools > Android > AVD Manager)](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#viewing).

As a i work with Cordova, I did not think of it before. I hope that this help the people that have the same problem that i had.

Answer (score 1):

If you, just like me, don't want to use Android Studio, you have two alternatives:

1. Use [this Windows-only GUI](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/gui-sdk-manager-for-newer-versions-of-android-tools.80090/) some 3rd-party developers made.
2. Deal with the CLI.

To install stuff via the CLI the easiest way I found was:

```
./sdkmanager --update
./sdkmanager --list > log.txt
(Find the packages you want reading log.txt)
./sdkmanager --install "package_name_in_quotes"
```

These are Linux instructions, but the only real difference on Windows is that you'll use `sdkmanager.bat` instead of `./sdkmanager`.

Don't forget to actually go to the directory before running these commands, in my case that would be `cd /opt/android/tools/bin`.